# How to get the Ad final url with the Facebook insights API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to get an ad final url using the python sdk.

I tried all the fields but I can't manage to find one which returns the ad url. At the moment my fields are:

```
params = {'access_token':creds.refresh_token,
          'fields':'action_values, actions, ad_name, adset_name, objective, outbound_clicks, outbound_clicks_ctr,  call_to_action_clicks, campaign_name, cost_per_unique_click, cpc, cpm, spend, website_ctr, date_start, date_stop',
          'action_breakdowns':['action_link_click_destination'],
          'date_presets':'last_year',
        # 'time_range':" since:2017-06-01, until:2017-01-03}"
}
ad_insights = requests.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{}/insights".format(ad['id']), params=params)
```

I understand that some ads won't have a final url, like boosting posts, but many ads are only pointing to a site, how can I get the "call to action url" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pull in the adCreative for each ad that AdInsights reports on. The adCreative will contain the outbound link.

See here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative

The following fields may be of interest to you

- object_url
- url_tags

Comment: In my case, the url_tags field contains the URL's utm_ parameters, but the object_url always comes out empty. :-\

Comment: I found the URL in `$adCreative->object_story_spec['link_data']['link']` (I'm talking PHP, here, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant but for those that land here... I was facing the same issue.

Here's the solution: `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{creative_id}?fields=object_story_spec&access_token={access_token}`

A good way to go about it is:

1. Get the list of your creative ids: `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/act_798134188164544/adcreatives?access_token={access_token}`
2. Take a specific id you want info about and use the above url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{creative_id}?fields=object_story_spec&access_token={access_token}`